# Error installing MVC3 on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I tried to install MVC3 on Visual Studio 2010 by following this link, but got an error as shown in image.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upgrade your Web Platform Installer to 4.0 found here: http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

If that fails you can always install MVC 3 manually here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1491